# Lie algebra of vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, vector-bundles

I have some conceptual confusion when thinking about the Lie algebra of a set of vector fields. Below, there are two questions which refer to the same problem, but from different viewpoints. Any comments/suggestions are greatly appreciated. Sorry if my questions appear silly.

Let $V=\{V_i\}$, $i=1,\dots,m$ be a set of vector fields on a smooth manifold $M$, $dim(M)=n\ge m$. Let $L(V)$ be a non-involutive Lie algebra of vector fields $V$.

1. For any $p\in M$, $L(V)$ is an infinite-dimensional group acting locally on some neighborhood $U(p)\subset M$ of $p$. Any group action can be seen as $\exp(t\cdot v):U(p)\rightarrow U(p)$, where $v\in L(V)$. Here comes my first problem. 
   When we look at elements of $L(V)$, these are all vector fields. If we consider them is being elements of a vector space, these form an infinite dimensional set. However, vector fields belong to a more general object: a module over $C^\infty(M)$. As such, they form a finite-dimensional set. Thant is, we can always find a set of basis vector fields and express the remaining ones as linear combinations (over $C^\infty$) of the basis v.f.'s. I wonder, how infinite-dimensionality enters the picture? Is there something that cannot be expressed using a finite-dim. basis?
2. When we think about the Lie algebra of a Lie group $G$, it is basically the same at each point $g\in G$. This is not true for the Lie algebra of vector fields. Would it make sense to speak about rank of the Lie algebra $L(V)$ at some point $p\in M$, to say that $p$ is a critical point of the Lie algebra etc? If so, how should we consider the rank of $L(V)$ at $p$? As the rank of vector fields $v\in L(V)$ at $p$? Obviously, it cannot be higher than $n$. So, again, we have an inf-dim set whose rank does not exceed $n$ locally.

Comment: About "how infinite dimensionality enters the picture": $\mathcal C^\infty(M)$ is itself an infinite dimensional vector space (over $\Bbb R$, I suppose), that's how. But you cannot speak of dimension over $\mathcal C^\infty(M)$ since it isn't a field; you can talk about rank in case of free modules over it.

Comment: @Marc, thank you. I see the point. Also the reference to free modules is useful.

Answer (score 3):

As for 1: it is infinite dimensional over the extremely small field $\mathbb{C}$ (which if you want can be seen as the tiny subset of constant functions within $C^\infty(M)$). Anything which is finite- but positive dimensional over $C^\infty(M)$ is infinite dimensional over $\mathbb{C}$ since $C^\infty(M)$ is itself infinite dimensional over $\mathbb{C}$.

For 2: The reason $Lie(G)$, viewed as a Lie algebra of vectorfields on $G$ is the same at every point is that we do not take ALL vectorfields, but only the $G$-invariant ones. This has no analogon in on the general manifold $M$, unless $M$ itself comes with a $G$-action.

What you describe here is looking at the Lie algebra structure at the tangent space  $T_pM$to $M$ at $p$. An element of the tangent space is called a tangent vector. It is defined as an equivalence class of vector fields on $M$ under the equivalence relation 'having the same value at point $p$'. You can see that the Lie algebra structure on vector fields respects the equivalence relation so indeed it defines a Lie algebra structure on $T_pM$, turning it into an $n$-dimensional Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$.

Only looking at equivalence classes of vector fields in your Lie algebra $L(V)$ gives a smaller (at most $m$-dimensional but perhaps even smaller) Lie subalgebra. It could be any Lie subalgebra of $T_pM$ including the one that only consists of the single element $0$.

Comment: thank you for the reply. May I ask a follow-up question? Would it may sense from the Lie-algebraic viewpoint to consider the local behavior of $L(V)\big|_p$? For instance, a rank deficiency of  $L(V)$ over $S\subset M$ could suggest that $S$ could be an invariant manifold. It seems though that asking such questions is not common in the Lie-algebraic context.

Comment: There is certainly a core of truth to this. An easy example is to define $L(V)$ as the set of all vector fields that vanish at a point $p$. Then in $p$ we get a much smaller Lie algebra than what we get at other points and this in turn points to the specialness of $p$ from the perspective or $L(V)$ or indeed it being left invariant by $exp(L(V))$. However you need to be careful. Suppose that $M$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$ and all the flow of all vector fields in $L(V)$ is parallel to the $x$-axis. Then I don't see how the 1-dimensionality of the induced Lie algebras at points would detect this.

Comment: Sure, the Lie subalgebras of $T_pM$ coming from $L(V)$ are 1-dimensional while $T_pM$ itself is 2-dimensional, but this holds in every point and hence also 'along' every line $S$, not just along the horizontal lines you wanted to detect. So apparently you really need more information relating vectors in the different $T_pM$ to each other, such as a connection.

Comment: The situation that you described corresponds to an involutive Lie algebra. So you can conclude that there is a foliation of $M$. I'd more interested in the case where the Lie algebra is non-involutive, but there are some local peculiarities. Also, do you have any particular example in mind on using connections in this context?

Comment: No, I was just thinking about it, but I cannot think of a good way to encode the connection information in a pure Lie-algebra language. Then again, I am not an expert in geometry at all. The remark on involutions and foliations is interesting, I overlooked it in the original question. Perhaps you should ask your followup question about invariant submanifolds as a seperate question on the front page. Some other people may have something to add here.